# Inno Setup modular installation

Tags: installation

I'm trying to release a program with a client/database approach.

The client and database can be installed on 2 different computers.

What I'm trying to do is an installer that at the beginning asks if you want to install the client, the database or both.

Is this possible? Which section should I modify?

I warn you, I've never wrote an Inno Setup script, I always used ISTools, but if there is no other way, I'm ready to get my hands dirty :P

Edit: a bit more info.
At the moment I have 3 installers, one for the client, one for the DB (which is postgreSQL) and one for PDFCreator.
What I'm doing is copy the files to a directory and then ask at the user what he wants to install: [Run] section, Post Installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Take a look at the CodeDlg.iss example.  It show how to create a dialog to ask which edition to install.  In the case of CodeDlg, it is various editions of a program (light, sponsored, paid) but the concept is the same.  I've done this before as well.  In my case, during initialization, I read a registry setting and set some variables up to choose which version (client or server) I install.  I don't have it here but will get it later and add to this answer.

Comment: I looked and it is indeed what I want to achieve. Just a question: what's the order of execution of the functions? IE: where do I call the initial function? Is it a standard named function that is always called at the beginning?

Comment: In the help file under "Pascal Scripting: Event Functions", there is a list of all of the event function and what they are for.  For example, the InitializeSetup function is described as "Called during Setup's initialization. Return False to abort Setup, True otherwise."   For example, I use that function to determine, in an update, whether the original program is installed and if not, display a message and exit.